# cant get binary to print horizontal and to stop exacution

Tags: java, printing, binary, while-loop

I am making a program that is converting from decimal to binary, octal, and hexadecimal. I am only focusing on the decimal to binary part in this so far. My problems are that the binary when I ask it to convert up to said number print them vertically not horizontally like 010. Also my while statement does not stop exacution if the y input is greater than 1024, which is the highest value I want to be able to be accepted.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DNS
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int y;
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
    do
    {   
        System.out.println("java DisplayNumberSystems");
        System.out.println("Enter a decimal value to display to: ");
        y = input.nextInt();

        for(int x=0; x <=y; x++)
        {
            convertToBinary(x);
        }
    }
    while(y <=1024);    

    }

    public static void convertToBinary(int x)
    {
        if(x >0)
        {
            convertToBinary(x/2);
            System.out.print(x%2 + " ");

        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

Comment: The method calls itself recursively, and you're calling `println()` at each step. `println()` prints a new line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove         `System.out.println("");` from     `public static void convertToBinary(int x)`
  you will be able to print horizontally

and change your do-while to simple while like this

```
    int y;
    Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in);
    System.out.println("java DisplayNumberSystems");
    System.out.println("Enter a decimal value to display to: ");
    y = input.nextInt();

    while(y <=1024)
{   

    for(int x=0; x <=y; x++)
    {
        convertToBinary(x);
    }
}
```

you were checking if y<=1024 after calling convertToBinary() method. you have check if y<=1024 before making a call to convertToBinary() method.

Answer (score 0):

You probably meant to have the empty `System.out.println()` call (by the way, you can call it with no arguments) after the call to `convertToBinary(x)` in the main `for` loop - otherwise empty lines are being printed during each recursion step of each number being evaluated.

```
for (int x = 0; x <= y; x++) {
    convertToBinary(x);
    System.out.println();
}
```

Regarding your other question about stopping if the input is larger than 1024 - this is because the calls to `convertToBinary(x)` are happening before the check in the `while` statement. You will need to explicitly `break` out of the loop to stop this. Personally, I would just use an infinite `while` loop with explicit checks:

```
while (true) {
    System.out.println("java DisplayNumberSystems");
    System.out.println("Enter a decimal value to display to: ");
    y = input.nextInt();

    if (y < 0) {
        System.out.println("That number is not positive!");
        break;
    }

    if (y > 1024) {
        System.out.println("That number is too big!");
        break;
    }

    for (int x = 0; x <= y; x++) {
        convertToBinary(x);
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```